# Reg-ex with different symbols

Tags: regex

Im using the following reg-ex which is working great but the only problem is
that you cannot mix symbols like

```
aaa-bbbb\ccc
```

it always should have the same sperator

like `aaa-bbb-cccc`

```
"^(?:(?:-?[A-z0-9]+)*|(?:_?[A-z0-9]+)*|(?:\/?[A-z0-9]+/?)*)\s*$"
```

How can I change it ?

The **Value** should have

```
hyphen ‘-‘,
Underscore ‘_’
Slash ‘/’
```

Comment: Provide some valid inputs values

Comment: You can use a back reference within the pattern to refer to something that was matched earlier …

Comment: `(?:(?:[-\/_]?[A-z0-9]*))\s*` - try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `A-z` gives you too wide of a range. In ASCII (and Unicode) there are characters between uppercase 'Z' and lowercase 'a' that are not letters or numbers. You can use the regex escape sequence `\w` for word characters or `A-Za-z`. Both are equivalent.

Also, it looks like you know you'll always have three sections so the lazy indicators are unnecessary.

```
[A-Za-z\d]+([-_\\/])[A-Za-z\d]+\1[A-Za-z\d]+\s*
```

This will ensure you have the same separator which can be a hyphen, slash, or underscore. Whatever the separator is it will separate 3 groups of alphanumeric characters.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This is what he's looking for but you can't use `\w` because it matches `_` character. (also, if you were using `\w` you wouldn't need `\d`, since `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

Comment: @OGHaza Whoops... Updated

Comment: @Chad: Be careful, `\w` and `[A-Za-z0-9_]` are not always equivalent. `\w` can include accentued letters depending on locales, or, in an unicode context, it can match all letters and all digits of all the alphabets of the unicode table.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure the symbol is the same throughout you should use a back reference, e.g.

```
aaa[_/-]bbb\1ccc
           ^^
```

The `\1` will have to be whatever symbol was matched in the `[_/-]`

Also you are using `[A-z]` which almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does, the characters between uppercase A and lowercase z are:

```
ABCD...XYZ[\]^_`abcd...xyz
```

You probably want `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Not sure that I got you do you have proposal ?[A-Za-z] will not work I need also numbers and symbols like I write...

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you'd also have `0-9` (or `\d`) in there. You can see chad's answer for a more complete solution.